# Filtering out an array for only images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So i have an array that has many file types. These are all under array.contentType. What i want, is to just have it return images, so array.contentType.images? i think.

Here is the code:

```
    const renderSlides = attachmentInfo.map((item,index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            {item.contentType === 'image/jpeg' ? <img src={item.url} /> : ''}
            <p className="legend">{item.name}</p>
        </div>
    ));
```

My guess is i need to change the .map to .filter, but i've never used .filter. And from what i've read online its a bit confusing. The ternary works, but it returns a blank screen in my carousel slide for everything that isn't an image. What i want is JUST the images.

Comment: you need a combination of filter and map. filter out the ones where file is image and then map over it. you don't need ternary in map then

Comment: So do the above map, and inside that do an item.filter?

Comment: no first filter with condition `item.contentType === 'image/jpeg'` and then map over it. you can chain the filter and map call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.filter` produces a new array where items match the predicate (function returning a boolean) provided.

For example:

```js
console.log([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3].filter(x => x >= 1));
```

would result in the value:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

A `filter` method call will have to be placed in front of the call to the `map` method. Additionally, all images have a content type starting with "`image/`", so checking for images can be generalized as well. Putting these both together would result in the following code:

```js
    const renderSlides = attachmentInfo.filter(({contentType}) =>
        contentType.startsWith('image/')
    ).map((item,index) =>
        <div key={index}>
            <img src={item.url} />
            <p className="legend">{item.name}</p>
        </div>
    );
```